# Installing iOS App Directly From Safari Web UI?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

I was using a website, and noticed that from my iphone on Safari, I could directly install their app from the Web UI. This was from the top of the page at https://flytap.com/ . I can't find what this is called or how to do it anywhere in the iOS documentation. This only seems to work in Safari.

Does anyone know what they are doing, or how I can do it?

[image: Installing iPhone App From Safari Web UI]

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/promoting_apps_with_smart_app_banners

Comment: If you answer the question, I can mark it correct.

Comment: @spierce7 - Answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is done via adding Universal Link support ([documentation here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016308-CH12-SW1)).
The banner you are seeing is the Universal Link smart banner ([documentation here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/promoting_apps_with_smart_app_banners#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002051-CH6)).

In-short, you should have a website, the website should be SSL enabled, you need to add an apple-app-site-association-file which defines the links your app needs to handle, make changes in your app to handle Universal Links and you should be good to go.

The app you shared has its [apple-app-site-association file here](https://flytap.com/.well-known/apple-app-site-association). You can view this file for any app that supports Universal Links using the pattern https://<SITE_BASE_URL>/.well-known/apple-app-site-association or https://<SITE_BASE_URL>/apple-app-site-association.